# REST API: How do you clear a Picklist value?

Tags: rest

Using the rest API, I want to be able to clear the value of a Picklist item. For example, I have the Account SObject which has an Industry Picklist. Using the Salesforce website, I can set the value of this to empty string by selecting the `--None--` option.
Using the REST API when attempting to set to nothing, the value is ignored:

```
{"Name":"Grand Hotels & Resorts", "Industry":""}
```

You can also see this behavior on the Salesforce workbench update page. Update an Account. Clear the Industry field and confirm the update. It is ignored.

Comment: Your JSON works in my org correctly. I suspect that you have a trigger or some logic turned on that's automatically cleaning your data. Try setting some debug logs in Setup > Logs > Debug Logs, and check the results after running an API call.

Comment: Have you checked the "Strictly enforce picklist values" ... try to uncheck this and try your code

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on Salesforce Workbench using API version 49.0

URL:

```
/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Account/0010p00000owzrK
```

JSON body:

```
{
    "Name":"Grand Hotels & Resorts",
    "Industry": ""
}
```

HTTP method: `PATCH`

Answer (score 0):

You will try to something like this:

```
Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    string url = 'https://test1-for-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/0012800000iCVLi?_HttpMethod=PATCH';
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+userInfo.getSessionId());
    req.setBody('{"Industry" : ""}');
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    system.debug('::::res:::'+res);
```

In debug log you will get

> USER_DEBUG|
>
> > [10]|DEBUG|::::res:::System.HttpResponse[Status=No Content,
> >     StatusCode=204]

something like these, but the Account have to updated.

check your particular account record

Answer (score 0):

I send this value `";"` and it worked for me